# Controlling a chrome print preview with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Is it possible to attach a script to the Chrome print preview dialog?

I want to control what happens when the user clicks the cancel button.

Kind of like a print.css but a print.js which allows me to control the print dialog.